# Include a 'extra' header when exporting data from SQL to csv

Tags: csv

I have a table in SQL that I need to export to csv each month.

The thing is that on top of the column headers a 'extra' header should appear showing 'Windows-1252" (as this csv gets uploaded in another system which needs to know this).

I can't find a way to add the extra header on top of the csv.

Any thoughts, thanks,

Ronny

Comment: At first pass I'd say that this is not possible using a standard export routine. You will possibly need to look at writing a script to do this. However, please advise what SQL database you are using (i.e. mySql, SQL Server 2016 etc), what tool you are using to do the export (i.e. WorkBench, SSMS) and what OS you are on (Windows or Linux) to help someone to provide you with an answer & possibly a script to achieve your goal.

Comment: ok. I am using SQL 2014. Preferably using SSIS or SSMS and I am on OS Windows NT 6.2